# If optimizations are enabled will the JIT always inline this method?

Tags: c#, jit, heuristics, inline-method

I am not expecting a definite yes or no. Any knowledge you might have I will consider as an answer.

```
private String CalculateCharge(Nullable<Decimal> bill, Nullable<Decimal> rate)
{
    return ((bill ?? 0.0m) * (rate ?? 0.0m)).ToString("C");
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say "yes" to this, but since it is private, I would assume so.

Comment: The C# compiler never inlines *anything*. For a list of optimizations the C# compiler -- rather than the jit compiler -- performs, see my article on the subject. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx

Comment: Thanks Eric, looks like I have a lot of reading to do.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Inlining is an implementation detail of the JIT, not of the C# compiler. From [Eric Gunnerson's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64717.aspx):

> The JIT uses a number of heuristics to
>   decide whether a method should be
>   in-lined.
>   The following is a list of
>   the more significant of those (note
>   that this is not exhaustive):
>
> - Methods that are greater than 32 bytes of IL will not be inlined.
> - Virtual functions are not inlined.
> - Methods that have complex flow control will not be in-lined. Complex
>     flow control is any flow control other
>     than if/then/else; in this case,
>     switch or while.
> - Methods that contain exception-handling blocks are not
>     inlined, though methods that throw
>     exceptions are still candidates for
>     inlining.
> - **If any of the method's formal arguments are structs, the method will
>     not be inlined.**

Although your method is quite short and not very complex so it might match the heuristics, `Nullable<T>` is a `struct` so I'd guess your method is not inlined.

As a rule of thumb, if inlining this method improves performance, the JIT will inline this method; otherwise it will not. But this is really an implementation detail of the JIT and nothing you should code for:

> I would **carefully consider explicitly coding for these heuristics** because they might change in future versions of the JIT. Don't compromise the correctness of the method to attempt to guarantee that it will be inlined.

**EDIT:** Apparently the bit about structs not being inlined is out-of-date; updated information can be found at [Vance Morrison's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/05/12/what-s-coming-in-net-runtime-performance-in-version-v3-5-sp1.aspx).

Comment: The struct option is no longer true as of .NET 3.5sp1.  struct parameters can be inlined now.